# ASP.NET connection error in sqlconnection

Tags: c#, asp.net

Can you please help me

```
Sqlconnection con;//**error**[The type or namespace name 'Sqlconnection' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?]

Sqlcommand com;//**error**[The type or namespace name 'Sqlcommand' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?]
```

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about a typo.

Comment: Like D Stanley pointed out in his answer, C# is case sensitive.

Comment: @Renan B.S that's a typo on a code

Comment: Using System.Data.SqlClient ? And then use cntrl- space key on the class name?

Comment: @DaveZych I gave that a second thought, and you're right. I've retracted the close vote.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You're missing a capital `C` - C# is case-sensitive:

```
SqlConnection
SqlCommand 
   ^
   |
   |
```

You also need to make sure you've referenced `System.Data.DLL` and included the namespace in your `using` block at the top of the class:

```
using System.Data.SqlClient;
```